# Arduino Mega / Robo r1 plus get pos - two or more data types

Tags: c++, arduino

I have no idea whats going on here. I have changed the code from `fpos_t` to `fatpos_t`, I did so in all instances but now my code is crashing at

two or more data types in declaration of 'getpos'

```
FatPos_t void SdBaseFile::getpos(FatPos_t* pos) {
    pos->position = curPosition_;
    pos->cluster = curCluster_;
}
```

Comment: `FatPos_t void` - what exactly is this supposed to achieve? It is declaring two different return types, which is not allowed

Comment: I was told to change the orginal fpos_t with this arduino robo3dr1plusvs script to flash the firmware in my printer. It is only moving up, but the script is old and arduino is updated to 1.8.5 so i dont think it likes fpos_t?

Comment: I highly doubt the function had two return types declared before your changes, that wouldn't have compiled either. Remove the first `FatPost_t` since your function isn't returning anything, the return type should be just `void`

Comment: Thank you, that worked, sadly though the printer is still not working right.